# MySQL condição com LIKE no PDO do PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estava habituado em usar a condição `LIKE` passando o parâmetro na conexão com o `MySQL` e `PHP` via `MySQLi`, e passei a usar `PDO` e não é selecionado nenhum resultado ao passar o valor para a condição através do parâmetro.

Retorna **0 registro** passando um parâmetro na condição LIKE`

```
$query = "SELECT po.post_id, po.*, cat.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_galeria WHERE gal_post_token = po.post_token) AS count_gal 
FROM posts AS po 
LEFT JOIN post_categorias AS cat 
ON po.post_cat = cat.cat_id 
WHERE po.post_cat <> '' 
AND po.post_titulo LIKE '%:termSearch%' 
OR po.post_conteudo LIKE '%:termSearch%' 
AND po.post_capa IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY po.post_data_cad DESC ;";

$stmt = $myconn->prepare($sql_data);
$stmt->bindParam(":termSearch", $termSearch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();

echo "COUNT: " . $total; // 0 return
```

O valor da variável `$termSearch` foi conferido e está sendo passado corretamente, esse não é o problema.

Retorna **todos os registros** alterando o parâmetro para um valor estático na condição `LIKE`

```
$query = "SELECT po.post_id, po.*, cat.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_galeria WHERE gal_post_token = po.post_token) AS count_gal 
FROM posts AS po 
LEFT JOIN post_categorias AS cat 
ON po.post_cat = cat.cat_id 
WHERE po.post_cat <> '' 
AND po.post_titulo LIKE '%camisetas%' 
OR po.post_conteudo LIKE '%camisetas%' 
AND po.post_capa IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY po.post_data_cad DESC ;";

$stmt = $myconn->prepare($sql_data);
// $stmt->bindParam(":termSearch", $termSearch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();

echo "COUNT: " . $total; // Todos os 543 registros
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um erro clássico quando se começa com PDO, na sua SQL faça essas alterações no local aonde tem `LIKE`:

```
"SELECT po.post_id, po.*, cat.*, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_galeria WHERE gal_post_token = po.post_token) 
    AS count_gal 
    FROM posts AS po 
    LEFT JOIN post_categorias AS cat 
    ON po.post_cat = cat.cat_id 
    WHERE po.post_cat <> '' 
    AND po.post_titulo LIKE :termSearch 
    OR po.post_conteudo LIKE :termSearch
    AND po.post_capa IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY po.post_data_cad DESC ;";
```

colocando somente o local e nome para substituição.

No momento de passar o valor na variável passe também o *porcento* (`%`) como no código a seguir:

```
$termSearch = '%camiseta%'; // <-------
$stmt = $myconn->prepare($sql_data);
$stmt->bindParam(":termSearch", $termSearch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [The PDO class](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo)
- [bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
- [Using LIKE in bindParam for a MySQL PDO Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068230/using-like-in-bindparam-for-a-mysql-pdo-query)

Comment: @EliseuB. vou deixar do jeito que eu fiz na minha máquina e por favor exclua esse monte de mensagem ...